# Does a static change anything to const in an automatic variable?

Tags: c, variables, static, constants

Consider the following function that is called periodically:

```
void func(void)
{
    const int myConstArray[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    // Doing some operations including the above array
}
```

If one changes the `myConstArray` from `const` to `static const`, does that change anything at all on how the code compiles?

Comment: That's what godbolt is for.

Comment: Yes, I forgot the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `const` to `static const` changes the *storage duration* of the object. When the array is declared `const int myConstArray[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};` inside a function, it has *automatic* storage duration, meaning memory is reserved for it from the time execution of its associated block starts until that execution of the block ends. Changing the declaration to `static const int myConstArray[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};` gives it *static* storage duration, meaning memory is reserved for it for the entire program.

Now, if the program does not make any use of the longer storage duration, then the compiler does not have to do anything differently. Consider this code:

```
int foo(int x)
{
    static const int Table[] = { 1, 5, 3, 6 };
    return Table[x];
}
```

In this code, the compiler can see `Table` is only used to look up a value. Therefore, it does not need to exist when the function is not executing—the program behaves the same whether the memory is reserved for `Table` or not, so it does not matter if it is declared `static` or not.

Compare that to this code:

```
int foo(int x)
{
    static const int Table[] = { 1, 5, 3, 6 };
    bar(Table);
    return Table[x];
}
```

Here the function passes the address of `Table` to `bar`. The compiler does not know what `bar` is going to do with that address. `bar` might store the address, to be used later in the program by some other routine. In this case, it matters whether `Table` is `static` or not. If `Table` is not `static`, its lifetime does not extend beyond the execution of `foo`, so its address should not be used later (if it is, the program behavior is not defined by the C standard). This means the compiler may use stack space for `Table`. However, if `Table` is declared with `static`, its address can be used after execution of `foo`, so the compiler must reserve memory for it even after execution of `foo` ends.

Finally, consider this code:

```
int foo(int x)
{
    const int Table[] = { 1, 5, 3, 6 };
    bar(Table);
    return Table[x];
}
```

Since `Table` is not declared `static`, each time `foo` is called, the `Table` in it is a new object in the semantics of the C standard. Further, all different objects must have different addresses (except the subobject at the start of a containing object, such as an array and its first element or a structure and its first member). So, if `bar` calls `foo` recursively, a second `Table` is created and `bar` is called again. Since the two `Table` objects must be different, `bar` must be passed a different address. This means that, with `Table` not declared `static`, the compiler may be compelled to create a new instance of it on the stack each time `foo` is called. To avoid this, it is preferable to declare `Table` with `static`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So in practice, the variable inside of a function that is declared const (but not static), can be still placed in the data memory segment instead of program memory? Does this mean that all "local" constants should be set as static const to save RAM?

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło: Often it will not make a difference, but there are some situations where it is preferable to declare constants as `static`. I added an example to the answer about that. I cannot think of an example where there is a benefit to not declaring a constant `static` outside of contrived situations where multiple instances of an object are needed for some exotic reason. So one should probably default to using `static`.